# Show all table borders except for surrounding ones

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: Table 1]

but I'm struggling to do it the whole day. For the record, it needs to be the `<table>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/pgnzyht6/

**html**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

td + td,
th + th{ border-left: 1px solid; }
tr + tr{ border-top: 1px solid; }
```